# How to properly use bootstrap grid?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create a log in page using bootstrap. I have created 2 div with each having col-lg-5 and col-lg-7. I'm trying to place a image at the left side div and login form at the right side div. But what I get is col-lg-5 at top and col-lg-7 always at bottom in any screen resolution. Can some one help me to identify what I'm doing wrong here.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <section class="Form my-4 mx-5">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">

              <div class="col-lg-5">
                <img src="./images/login2.png"   alt="">
              </div>

              <div class="col-lg-7">
                <form action="">
                  <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col-lg-7">
                      <input type="email" placeholder="Email-Address" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col-lg-7">
                      <input type="passsword" placeholder="******" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col-lg-7">
                      <button type="button" class="btn1">Login</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  
                  <a href="#">Forgot Password</a>
                  <p>Don't have a account yet? <a href="#">Register here</a></p>
                </form>
              </div>
              
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like you have an unwanted `div.col` as the only child of your `div.row` instead of your real columns..

Comment: Just a FYI, you could always look into CSS Flexbox as an alternative.  Helpful link for learning  https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an incorrect nesting of row and cols. Please read up [how the grid system of bootstrap works](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/grid/). It is essential to understand how the classes need to be nested to achieve a working row / column relationship.

To keep it short: Cols should always be nested directly under rows to get the best result.

In your example you have your col-5 and col-7 nested under a single col element. Remove this element and it should work as expected

Another hint, your input fields are all missing some labels. You are misusing the placeholder attribute as a label, this is wrong.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-5"> </div>
  <div class="col-lg-7"> </div>
</div>
```